# Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined in WordPress Visual Composer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, d3.js, wpbakery

I want to edit some images which can only be done in WPBakery Page Builder. So, when I try to edit the page with it, the frontend editor (page builder) doesn't loads. Console shows the following error:

[image]

Although, the library script tag is added before the tag which is using this library:
[image]

I don't know if any of this makes sense, but, yeah, I have tried these solutions because they were mentioned on different forums:

- Adding `charset="utf-8"` to external script tag.
- Moving the script tag inside Raw HTML element.
- Using `$(document).ready(function(){})` to enclose the whole of second
  script. So, that it loads after everything is loaded.

Unfortunately, none of these worked for me.

The page builder works fine on pages where I don't use the `d3.js` library. And, the visualization works fine WHEN NOT IN PAGE BUILDER - the library loads up and the visualization is displayed. You can check it out here:
https://conductscience.com/age-when-charles-darwin/

Also, please note that I don't have access to any of the theme files. So, I can't make any changes to `functions.php` or any other file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to the WPBakery, not Visual Composer plugin. You need to have the latest version 5.7 in order to fix this issue. More information, contact support.wpbakery.com if you have a valid license.